# Calculating all the unordered pairs across multiple sets

Tags: algorithm, combinations

Suppose I have a set `{s_1, s_2, ..., s_r}` where every `s_i` is itself a set of integers. The desired output is a set of all the sets `{a, b}` where `a` and `b` occur together in at least one `s_i` (and `a != b`). For example, on input `{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {5}}` the desired output is `{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}}`.

Obviously, in the worst case where the intersection of any `s_i` and `s_j` is empty, you have to go through and calculate all the combinations of length 2 (call them *pairs*). But in my case, there is a lot of overlap between the sets. I suspect one optimization that could be made has to do with the fact that if you've already calculated the pairs of `s_i`, and `s_j - s_i = k` then for `s_j` you need only calculate the pairs of `k` and then pair every element of `k` up with every element of `s_i`. The aim is then to match each `s_j` with a `s_i` that makes `k` small. But I'm not sure what the most efficient way to do this matching is, and perhaps there are even better optimizations to be had.

Answer (score 0):

One optimization that comes to mind is this. For each new set `S_i` find the difference `M_ix = S_i \ S_x` and also `N_ix = S_x \ S_i`, where `x` is every saved set prior to `i`. For each item in `M_ix` add new pairs (combined with `S_i`) to output. If `M_ix` is not empty for at least one `x` (`S_i` is not subset of all saved sets) then save `S_i`. If `N_ix` is empty for some `x` (`S_i` is superset of `S_x`) then discard `S_x` from list of saved sets.

Maintaining these saved set should reduce some time, at the cost of space.